# MailItem.Reply Event not working as expected

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

I want to write a script that changes the format of the mail, when I am replying to a text- or rtf-mail, using Outlook 2013. To have something to begin with. I used the reply event described in the [MS dev centre](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff860938%28v=office.15%29.aspx). Unfortunately the example does not work as I expect it to. For testing, I put in a simple message box that should pop up after clicking the reply button. I never see that message box. What did I do wrong?

```vb
Public WithEvents myItem As MailItem 

Sub Initialize_Handler() 

    Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 

End Sub 


Private Sub myItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 

    'Set Response.SaveSentMessageFolder = myItem.Parent
    MsgBox "I never see this message box :("

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the method promoted by Microsoft you need this code in ThisOutlookSession. It would be needed if the event code is not in this special class module.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Initialize_handler
End Sub
```

The method described in the answer from Max, where code is in Application_Startup rather than Initialize_handler, can be used if all code is in ThisOutookSession.

Comment: There appears to have been a change in the Initialize_Handler process. Now there is an error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490640/outlook-vba-find-properties-of-the-item-the-reply-is-originated-from. The new process https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239607/how-to-initialize-an-event-handler

Answer (score 2):

Do you click Reply in the Explorer or Inspector? Your code will only run if you click Reply button in an Inspector.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the difference is. I click the reply button in the ribbons of the Outlook main window, or the ribbons of the email window.

Comment: The window where Outlook show the list of emails is called Explorer. the window where you view or edit an email is called Inspector. Your code works only when a message is open in an Inspector and you click the Reply button.

Comment: I checked both, but the code is working neither in the explorer, nor in the inspector.

Comment: When does your Initialize_Handler sub run? Does it when the item is already being displayed? Try this in OutlookSpy: open a message, click the CurrentItem button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the Event tab. Hit Reply. Do you see Reply event logged at the bottom of the Events tab?

Comment: Dmitry, I will try this out next week, when I am back at the office. Meanwhile I let you know that my code is stored in "ThisOutlookSession".

Comment: If it runs in ThisOutlookSession, there is no  Application.ActiveInspector, so you will get an error. And if there is one, chances are you will have a different item open when you reply. You need to set an event sink on that particular mailitem, not on some random item that was open when Initialize_Handler ran. To do that, you will need to track Inspectors.NewInspector event and set up the event handler on the Inspector.CurrentItem object. You also need to take into account that you can have more than one item open ta the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sadly, I realize this is not as easy as I thought it would be. I will stop trying to get this working as I already invested a good amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put this into "ThisOutlookSession" - only there it will work!

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents objInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
   Set objInspectors = Outlook.Inspectors
end Sub

Private Sub objInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
            Set newItem = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
    Set Inspector = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub newItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
   newItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
   If newItem.Sent = True Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

This will work on any new mail-item, I do not know how to make this work only for replys. You could check the subject, if there is an subject already it will be an reply.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Max. However I am not looking for a workaround. The example from Microsoft *has to be working* as it is written for Outlook 2013 and I want to know why it is not for me. Cheers!