# How to initialize an event handler

Tags: vba, outlook

I found this code [online](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/auto-fill-email-subject-line-attachment-name-outlook/). It is supposed to auto populate my subject line with any attachments I provide. The code does not run.

I don't receive an error or anything that suggests its even going through the code.

```vb
Public WithEvents olInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Public WithEvents olMail As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub Initialize_handlers()
    Set olInspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub olInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    Dim olItem As Object
    Set olItem = Inspector.CurrentItem
    If TypeName(olItem) = "MailItem" Then Set olMail = olItem
End Sub

Private Sub olMail_AttachmentAdd(ByVal Attachment As Attachment)
    MsgBox "This is a test."
    If olMail.Subject = "" Then
      'If you don't want the prompt,
      'Just delete the Msgbox line and its corresponding "End if".
      If MsgBox("Do you want to use the attachment name as the subject", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
         olMail.Subject = Attachment.DisplayName
      End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Set an early breakpoint and when hit, single step through the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*There is nothing wrong with your code, you simply need to Initialize the Inspectors*

*Click on `Sub Initialize_handlers()` and press **F5***

```
Private Sub Initialize_handlers()
    Set olInspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub
```

*Or just use [Application.Startup Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/application-startup-event-outlook), Save it and restart Outlook then it should work*

*Example*

```
Public WithEvents olInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Public WithEvents olMail As Outlook.mailitem

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set olInspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub Initialize_handlers()
    Set olInspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub olInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    Dim olItem As Object
    Set olItem = Inspector.CurrentItem
    If TypeName(olItem) = "MailItem" Then Set olMail = olItem
End Sub

Private Sub olMail_AttachmentAdd(ByVal Attachment As Attachment)
    MsgBox "This is a test."
    If olMail.Subject = "" Then
      'If you don't want the prompt,
      'Just delete the Msgbox line and its corresponding "End if".
      If MsgBox("Do you want to use the attachment name as the subject", _
                                                     vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
         olMail.Subject = Attachment.DisplayName
      End If
    End If
End Sub
```