# How to initialize handler for ItemAdd code that is in a class module?

Tags: vba, outlook

Following by the letter the MS documentation - [link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemadd)

I am trying to initialize the handler in `Application_Startup`.

```vb
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Call Initialize_handler
End Sub
```

I get the error:

> Sub or function not defined.

I put the code in a new class module (as stated in the doc) and added the startup in ThisOutlookSession.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49246557/4539709

Comment: You have not provided enough code to recreate the problem. The information in the MS documentation has been valid previously. The extra step of using a class module, other than ThisOutlookSession, has caused problems as indicated in the example in the link in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

To call this in the Startup it seems you shall not put it in a class module but in the ThisOutlookSession.
I would definitely add this to the MS document page.
To provide feedback to the doc page it seems one shall ask in SO.
I am not sure Microsoft will see this. Let's see.