# Outlook VBA event handler not called

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following `ThisOutlookSession` in Outlook:

```
Public Sub Application_Startup()
    Call GetItemsFolderPath.Initialize
End Sub
```

And the following `GetItemsFolderPath` class module:

```
Public WithEvents myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer

Public Sub Initialize()
 Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub myOlExp_SelectionChange()
 MsgBox "Hello, world"
End Sub
```

I'm basically following the docs from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/office/vba/api/Outlook.Explorer.SelectionChange

- The code compiles BUT it *never* shows the MsgBox
- Restarting Outlook so `Application_Startup` is called didn't work
- Manually executing the `Application_Startup` macro didn't help either

Any ideas - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outlook events not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002026/outlook-events-not-firing)

Comment: @niton: I'm already following the accepted in the linked question, so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Is this VBA `Call GetItemsFolderPath.Initialize`?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Why shouldn't that be VBA?

Comment: I do not recognize it. The answer about using a class module https://stackoverflow.com/a/48550952/1571407, other than `ThisOutlookSession` seems to be popular. I do not see that used.

Comment: see if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49246557/4539709

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ran into the following problem:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/deployment/macros-in-this-project-disabled-outlook

Comment: That is not the original problem/question. I answered that. You should mark my answer as the answer that solved it and then write a new question.

Answer (score 0):

When adding Dim GetItemsFolderPath As New GetItemsFolderPath in global space, the code work as it should, displaying the messagebox when you switch folder in Outlook.

ThisOutlookSession:

```
Option Explicit

Dim GetItemsFolderPath As New GetItemsFolderPath 'Instantiate the class

'***************************************************
'* Outlook start
'*
Public Sub Application_Startup()
    Call GetItemsFolderPath.Initialize
End Sub
```

Class module GetItemsFolderPath:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer

Public Sub Initialize()
    Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub myOlExp_SelectionChange()
    MsgBox "Hello, world"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, instantiating the class was missing too. But for the real problem: see my answer.