# outlook vba find properties of the item the reply is originated from

Tags: vba, outlook

I have user-defined properties in my emails. I would like them to be copied in case of an reply to the new item (from the one, the reply was originated from).

This would not be the problem, but with the code below copied from
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.reply%28even%29
I get "VBA Error 91: Object Variable not set" when running Initialize_Handler

```
Public WithEvents myItem As MailItem 

Sub Initialize_Handler() 
  Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 
End Sub 

Private Sub myItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 
  ...code for copying user-defined properties...
End Sub
```

What causes this error? It even comes if "ThisOutlookSession" has only this code in it.

And am I looking the right way for getting values/properties from the original-email-item?

Thanks!
Max

Comment: not quite. I now found out what causes the problem: If i open a mail as window/inspector on its own, the reply-sub will fire. When i click reply in Outlook itself (the "main window"), the reply-sub does not fire. How can I achieve that?

Comment: meanwhile i see there is another problem/question....sorry... even when the reply.sub fires, I can not access the "old" email which the answer goes to for reading its properties

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no inspector window opened at the time when the following code runs:

```
Sub Initialize_Handler() 
  Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 
End Sub
```

The `ActiveInspector` returns Nothing in this case. You can read more about the error you get on the [Object variable not set (Error 91)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-variable-not-set-error-91) article.

Comment: as far as i know an "inspector window" would be a email opened as window, not in the preview. The code above runs at startup of Outlook, how could there be an email open then?

Answer (score 0):

on another page i found a solution that works. Here the full (adapted) code:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents objInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Public WithEvents objExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
Public WithEvents olitem As Outlook.mailitem

Private Sub Application_Startup()
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
 Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

 Set objInspectors = Outlook.Inspectors
 Set objExplorer = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer
End Sub
Private Sub objInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    Dim olitem As Object
    Set olitem = Inspector.CurrentItem
    If TypeName(olitem) = "MailItem" Then Set olitem = olitem
End Sub

Private Sub olitem_Forward(ByVal Forward As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
 Call kennzeichn_auto(olitem, Forward)
End Sub
Private Sub olitem_Reply(ByVal response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
 Call kennzeichn_auto(olitem, response)
End Sub
Private Sub olitem_ReplyAll(ByVal response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
 Call kennzeichn_auto(olitem, response)
End Sub
Sub kennzeichn_auto(olitem As mailitem, response As mailitem)
 Call AddUserProperty(response, "Kunde", wert_property(olitem, "Kunde"))
 Call AddUserProperty(response, "Bearbeiter", wert_property(olitem, "Bearbeiter"))
 Call AddUserProperty(response, "KundeNo", wert_property(olitem, "KundeNo"))
End Sub
```