# How to trap my reply to a Meeting Invite?

Tags: vba, outlook

When I reply to a meeting invite sent to one of my non-default email accounts, Outlook sends the replies from the default account instead of the account the invite was sent to.

I tried using the `ItemLoad` event to trap this situation and set a `MailItem` object to use in a `MailItem.Reply` event. I get a type error message in this line of code below `Set NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg = myObj`.

How can I set `NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg` to the meeting request's corresponding `MailItem` object so it will trigger the reply event?

```
Public WithEvents NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg As MailItem
Dim MeetingReplyDisplayName As String


Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    
    Dim myObj As Variant
    Set myObj = GetCurrentItem()
      
    If myObj.Class = olMeetingRequest And myObj.Parent.Store.DisplayName _
     <> Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Store.DisplayName Then
     
        Set NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg = myObj
        MeetingReplyDisplayName = myObj.Parent.Store.DisplayName
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
        Response.SendUsingAccount = MeetingReplyDisplayName
End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
         
    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select
     
    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: As you reply on a `MeetingItem`, shouldn't you use `MeetingItem_Reply` event instead of  `MailItem` ? `Set NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg = myObj` fails as `myObj` is checked for being `olMeetingRequest` what is a `MeetingItem` not a `MailItem`!

Comment: Thank you.  I had originally tried defining `NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg` as `MeetingItem`, but then `Private Sub NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)` was never triggered.  Wouldn't the above definition make this a `MeetingItem_Reply` event?

Comment: Code needs to be in `ThisOutlookSession`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029515/mailitem-reply-event-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I did have my code in `ThisOutlookSession`, but did not set up `Outlook.Inspectors` to capture the reply event.  I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

The item type received is a meeting request (olMeetingRequest) which is a MeetingItem.

`Public WithEvents NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg As MailItem` does not match so you get a type mismatch on `Set NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg = myObj`.

Instead use`Public WithEvents NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg As MeetingItem`.

---

Sample code to demonstrate event triggering on clicking Respond then Reply.

```
Public WithEvents NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg As MeetingItem

Dim MeetingReplyDisplayName As String

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "Procedure.......: Application_ItemLoad"
    Debug.Print " TypeName(Item).: " & TypeName(Item)
    
    Dim myObj As Object
    Set myObj = GetCurrentItem()
    Debug.Print " TypeName(myObj): " & TypeName(myObj)
    
    If myObj.Class = olMeetingRequest Then
        If myObj.Parent.Store.DisplayName <> GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Store.DisplayName Then
            Set NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg = myObj
            MeetingReplyDisplayName = myObj.Parent.Store.DisplayName
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "Procedure.........................: NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg_Reply"
    Debug.Print " TypeName(NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg): " & TypeName(NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg)
    Debug.Print " TypeName(Response)...............: " & TypeName(Response)
    MsgBox "Reply event triggered"
End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    
    Select Case TypeName(ActiveWindow)
    
        Case "Explorer"
            On Error Resume Next
            Set GetCurrentItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
            On Error GoTo 0
            
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
            
    End Select
     
End Function
```

Comment: When I use `Public WithEvents NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg As MailItem`, it will not trigger   the sub `NonDefaultMailboxMtgMsg_Reply` when I reply to the meeting.

Comment: I suggest the question you asked has been answered but you asked the wrong question. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.respond shows how to send a response to a meeting request.